# MDK vs IMK vs MK key differences

Tags: encryption, des

I don't understand whether they are different or not. Would you mind explaining them all?

- MK-AC, MK-SMI, MK-SMC
- MDK Encryption Key, MDK MAC, MDK AC
- IMK-AC, IMK-SMI, IMK-SMC

For example, in the generation of ICC Master Key(=**U**nique **D**erived **K**ey), EMV Book 2 on page 129, Option A uses *IMK* [while in Eftlab to generate the ICC Master Key, it uses *MDK*](https://www.eftlab.com/tutorials/cryptographic-calculator-emv-menu). It is obviously confusing.  Would you mind explaining them **all I list**?